# itext pdfacroform set value chinese problem

Tags: pdf, itext

all

I created a pdf template using libreoffice. I tried to fill chinese string into these field but only garbage in those fields. code like below:

```
            PdfFont kaiuFont = PdfFontFactory.createFont("c:/windows/fonts/kaiu.ttf", true);
            FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("d:/download/202106.pdf");
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(template), new PdfWriter(output));
            PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdf, true);
            Map<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.getFormFields();
            fields.get("COMPANY_TITLE").setValue(<Chinese words>).setFontAndSize(kaiuFont, 18f);
            pdf.close();
```

What's wrong with those code?

Comment: Have you tried providing font and size _before_ setting the value?

Comment: Thanks for your help, the first line I defined a chinese font kaiu.ttf. the 6th line I fill field with chinese character and set font to kaiu.tff. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Have you tried providing font and size before setting the value? I.e. first call `setFontAndSize` and then `setValue`?

Comment: mkl, Thanks, I just tried to set font before set value but still no luck.

Comment: OK. Was just an idea...

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore this topic if your pdf is not generated by LibreOffice. I google d for a day and found this solution link and it works for me

[libreoffice pdf issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44373635/acrofields-created-with-libre-office-are-not-code-fillable-unless-i-edit-the-pdf)

Comment: As that other stack overflow answer solved your issue, I closed your question as a duplicate thereof.